# Giving a test case where heap sort from Introduction to Algorithm fails

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort

I was reading heapsort from Introduction to Algorithms ,
It is stated there
(1)To build max heap in bottom up manner.
(2)Then exchange with last element and call max hepify on the first element and continues like this.

Lets take an example on this input-

```
->7 10 20 3 4 49 50
```

the steps in building max heap will be

```
7 10 50 3 4 49 20
7 10 50 3 4 49 20
50 10 7 3 4 49 20
```

this is max heap build up. Now we exchange with last

```
20 10 7 3 4 49 | 50
```

now we call max heapify on 20, nothing happens n we will put 20 in n-1 position which is wrong.

We are making heap in the bottom up manner but calling heapify in top down manner, I think this is why its giving wrong on this input.

Answer (score 5):

Your algorithm to build the max heap has an error. The array

```
50 10 7 3 4 49 20
```

Does not represent a valid max heap. In the traditional array representation, that array would correspond to this:

```
        50
    10      7
  3    4  49  20
```

That's not a valid heap because 49 and 20 are larger than their parent.

You need to fix your bottom-up heap construction algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your heap sort algorthm is incomplete. After the array is `50 10 7 3 4 49 20`,the max_heapify is again called on the 3rd node which will swap the 3rd and 6th value in the array making it the max heap `50 10 49 3 4 7 20`. Now you will swap the first element with the last element in the array and then call max_heapify on `n-1` elements and you will get your desired answer.

Comment: Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71136657/algorithm-clrs-solution-more-in-depth-discussion-need